# How to exclude collisions with ground from OnCollisionStay?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a wall running script for my player and I was experimenting with `OnCollisionStay` The only problem I have is that it detects collisions with ground and things I don't want it to check. Is there any way to get it to only check walls or check things I want it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use an if statement in your OnCollisionStay method and check the tag of the object you are colliding with:

   ```
   void OnCollisionStay(Collision coll) {
       if (coll.transform.tag.Equals("Wall")) {
           // Do wall related stuff
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set up layer based collision detection.  This documentation explains that: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Depending on what it is that you're trying to achieve one or a mix of both of these approaches should get you the results you're looking for.